# Debian packages: distinguish "requested install" from "installed to satisfy dependencies"

Tags: debian

How can I determine which packages where installed because **I requested** the installation and which packages where automatically installed in order to **satisfy dependencies**?

In aptitude, this information is shown as "A":

```
i A fam         ...
i   grub        ...
i A grub-common ...
```

This shows that I requested the package grub and that grub-common was installed as a result of this.  However, aptitude is an interactive program, I cannot extract this information automatically to process it with a script.

With the debian package management tool 'dpkg -l' or 'dpkg --get-selections', I can get a list of installed package with additional information.  E.g.

```
> dpkg -l
...
ii  grub                                 0.97-47lenny2              GRand Unified Bootloader (Legacy version)
ii  grub-common                          1.96+20080724-16           GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (common files)
ii  gs-common                            8.62.dfsg.1-3.2lenny1      Dummy package depending on ghostscript
...
```

This list can easily be processed with scripts, but it only shows that the packages are installed --- not whether by request or for dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

indeed one can call aptitude search with the so-called search patterns; see reference at http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03s05.html#tableSearchTermQuickGuide
search ~i yields installed packages. Using grep to discard packages with A gives packages not automatically installed, so it almost answers the original question.

But it includes packages that belong to the original distribution, so its not completely sorted out. In my case, its still 1500 packages, a set I can deal with.

Its probably possible to do it by search combination, I didnt dig, here is my command:

```
aptitude search ~i|grep -v '^i A'|
```

the grep -v discards dependent packages

Comment: Thank you very much! I used !~M to filter out automatically installed packages.  I dealt with the original distribution by running this search **before** installing additional packages:  Later, I can remove these packages from the result list.

Answer (score 1):

Aptitude runs as a commandline-only, gui-less program too. Try:

```
aptitude search grub
```

The information will be there.

Comment: excellent!  I digged into this and found that 'aptitude search ~M' will list all automatically installed packages.

Answer (score 0):

Apt supports an 'auto' flag which describes precisely this.

Look at http://man.he.net/man8/apt-mark and dig deeper if needed.