# RPM packages: distinguish “requested install” from “installed to satisfy dependencies”

Tags: dependencies, rpm

How can I determine which packages were installed because **I requested** the installation and which packages were automatically installed in order to **satisfy dependencies**?

(This is the same as [this question for Debian systems.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686386/debian-packages-distinguish-requested-install-from-installed-to-satisfy-depe))

Answer (score 0):

At least as of CentOS 5 I don't believe there is any such ability or marking in rpm/yum.

You can find out, using `package-cleanup --leaves` from the `yum-utils` package, which currently installed packages are leaves in the RPM database. (Add `--all` to have it include non-library packages in the list.)